# Timer scoping and proper disposal

Tags: c#

So I'm working on a Task Scheduling program using a System.Timers.Timer object to wait between tasks. For using this timer I'm throwing it into a static (extension) method on instantiation and using it only there. My question is will it be properly disposed of at the conclusion of that static method or do I need to do something more? Here's what I'm working with.

```
public static void Use<T>(this T o, Action<object> work) => work(o);

private void RunLoop()
{
    while (!Stop)
    {
        try
        {
            //Method 1
            new System.Timers.Timer((task.NextRun - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds).Use(timer => {
                timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
                    new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunProc)) {
                        Name = task.Title,
                        IsBackground = true
                    }.Start();
                };
                timer.AutoReset = false;
                timer.Start();
            });

            //Method 2
            using (var timer = new System.Timers.Timer((task.NextRun - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds))
            {
                timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunProc))
                    {
                        Name = task.Title,
                        IsBackground = true
                    }.Start();
                };
                timer.AutoReset = false;
                timer.Start();
            }

        } catch(SqlException ex)
        { //Omitted for size }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { //Omitted for size }
    }
}
```

Will method 1 properly dispose of my timer, or do I have to call dispose or deal with a using statement for GC to get it? From what I've been reading for most objects they will get GC'ed when they fall out of scope of that lambda call in Use. But apparently Timers are different in that they connect to some un-managed resources which can cause them to persist even when you would expect they'd get cleaned up, like say going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not technically required, Timers should always be disposed properly (just like nearly everything that inherits from IDisposable).  What will happen if you don't dispose the timers?  They will build up until a garbage collection detects that they're no longer reachable and then they will be finalized (which should automatically do the same thing as disposing of them, but it isn't as efficient).

In your method 2, the timer will likely not ever fire because it will be disposed immediately after it is created (before the Elapsed delegate runs).

So, the question becomes, when should you dispose of the timer?  Well, that depends on how it is used.  If you're only using it to execute that little code block once, you can dispose of it at the end of that execution.  If it's supposed to trigger more than once, you'll need to have some other outside owner of the timer that disposes of it when it is no longer needed.

Comment: This all exists within a windows service. It's only purpose is to count down the time to the next task to run. I was afraid of it getting disposed of before it could finish with Method 2. Method 1 is what I'm currently using and it works, I was just worried about creating a memory leak with how it's implemented. Created new for each iteration and used in the lambda then dropped from scope and recreated. I guess I could make a higher scoped timer, but at that point it will never get disposed, just reset. Not sure if that is better or not.

Comment: For a one-shot timer, you should dispose of it inside the event delegate.

Answer (score 0):

For closure, I ended up creating a list of timers for each action, and then just update the intervals, and recycle them as needed. Then added a specific function to properly stop and dispose of all of them, when stopping the service. The setup I have above fails once there are 2 tasks scheduled for the same time, so it wouldn't have worked either way. With this new way, I don't have to worry about it as they're either recycled indefinitely or specifically disposed of.